# Redisson not connecting to redis cluster

Tags: java, redis, redisson

Im trying to configure my java application to connect to a redis cluster using Redisson.
Following is my redisson client config:

```
Config config = new Config();
    config.useClusterServers()
            .addNodeAddress("redis://IP:6379", "redis://IP:6379", "redis://IP:6379");
    RedissonClient redisClient = Redisson.create(config);
    redisClient.getRemoteService();
```

** I have also tried by specifying only 1 ip in the above config.
The redis cluster is deployed on docker with the following config (6 node clsuter-- 3master 3slave) :

```
port 6379
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
protected-mode no
bind <NODE_IP>
```

** Have also tried without protected-mode and bind
However I always face the following exception :

```
WARN org.redisson.cluster.ClusterConnectionManager - connection timed out: IP/IP:6379|#]
```

I tried connecting using redis-cli to the my redis nodes from the deployment server and the connection was successful

Redisson version : 3.13.2
Redis image : redis:6

Im not very sure where am I going wrong and would appreciate some help

Comment: Looks like a networking issue, connection time out typically indicates that the host can be reached but the requested port is not open and/or a firewall is configured to ignore (not reject) incoming packets on not specifically allowed ports.

Comment: @DaniloTommasina thank you for your reply. 
I tried connecting from my java application node to the redis node using redis-cli-- it was successful 
Also, The application is able to connect to a standalone redis deployment

Comment: I'm not familiar with redis, but I see in your connection string you are using rediss (with a double s) is that a 'secure protocol' version of redis protocol? If it is, then it might be some issue with certificates, if it isn't then it's a typo :)

Comment: Soo incase of an ssl connection the connection string needs to have the double 's'.
I have tried both though :p

Comment: I will remove the 's' to avoid confusion